# Python like code execution of R from Terminal

Tags: r

In python we can run a python code:

```
python -c "import os;print(os.listdir('./'))"
```

My question is simple, how can we do a similar code execution of Rscript without opening R shell or writing a R script?

Something like :

```
Rscript -c "installed.packages()[,'Package']"
```

Comment: A discussion about `littler` vs `Rscript` is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205302/difference-between-rscript-and-littler

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just type `Rscript` you get

> Usage: /path/to/Rscript [--options] [-e expr [-e expr2 ...] | file] [args]
>
> ...
>
> Expressions (one or more '-e ') may be used *instead* of 'file'

Thus

```
Rscript -e "installed.packages()[,'Package']"
```

Another possibility is

```
echo "installed.packages()[,'Package']" | R --slave
```

(a little slower but more robust because it does things like load the `methods` package)

Comment: I just asked you a couple of days ago why you would use `| R --slave`.  Care to expand?

Comment: If I didn't have littler and I wanted to do something that required the `methods` package and I didn't want to use one of the other workarounds (explicitly add `library("methods")` or [set R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/Rscript.html).  I've noticed R-core members using this idiom (not that that necessarily makes it right).

Comment: On the other hand, it may be that littler works everywhere that Rscript  would anyway (I don't know what " only supported on systems with the execv system call" implies practically about Rscript's restrictions)

Comment: In an answer to the linked question from @spacedman you say "Rscript is now everywhere where R is", so provided littler is still non-Windows, `R --slave` might be a reasonable alternative to Rscript

Answer (score 4):

There's [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) for this, which manifests itself as an `r` command:

```
$ r -pe 'sqrt(2)'
[1] 1.414214
```

And the actual question can be answered thusly:

```
$ r -e'IP <- installed.packages(); print(head(IP[,"Package"]))'
    docopt   magrittr    stringi    stringr    littler       base 
  "docopt" "magrittr"  "stringi"  "stringr"  "littler"     "base"
```

Comment: I have to say that if I didn't know what docker was, the wrapping of the answer in a docker layer would be pretty confusing ...

Comment: i've docked the docker lines.